# All In One SEO Plugin - Category INDEX

Tags: plugins

Anyone know how to override noindex on certain categories?

I only want a few of my categories to be index but the rest not, in the All in one SEO plugin I have a setting that says "Use noindex for Categories"

What I was wondering if there was any way of overriding this on some categories but leave it in place for the majority of categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From quick look at code this is getting concatenated into `$meta_string` variable, that is echoed without passing through any filter and so not easily modifiable.

Likely for more precise control you need to disable this option in plugin and insert tag with your own code.